# Is it possible to do select on preload in ecto query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I need to select specific fields from the `Post` schema which have 10+ fields. 
I need to select preloaded `:comments` as well. How can I do that?

```
query = from p in Post, preload: [:comments], select: map(p, [:comments, :title])
Repo.all(query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, depending on what kind of data structure you want to receive as output. If you want a `%Post{}` struct with only the `comments` and `title` fields, use the following query:

```
query = from p in Post, preload: [:comments], select: [p.comments, p.title]
Repo.all(query)
```

Otherwise, please refer to the documentation for the [select](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#select/3) query expression :-)